# Synonymize [adoptopenjdk] to [java]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

I suggest to synonymize [adoptopenjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adoptopenjdk) to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Similar to how the [oraclejdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oraclejdk) and  [openjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk) tags are already synonyms of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: I also found [redhat-openjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redhat-openjdk/info), should that also be made a synonym?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend against this, and possibly revisit the synonym of oraclejdk and openjdk as well.

There could be questions about the specific runtime (which is what adoptopenjdk/temurin and openjdk represent) as opposed to the language (which, given the JRE, is only *one* thing).

For instance, I could be running Kotlin applications on adoptopenjdk.  Does that mean my question is about Java? No!